# Excel: if a vlookup has multiple values return one that is specified

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am trying to find a statement that will allow me to search through multiple values in column b, and if a value in column a has the specified value in column b then it should return true for every time the value in column a is present.

if(vlookup(a,a:b,2,false)=456,true,false) doesnt work because it only returns the first value

there are some index/match arguments i have tried, but i dont want a list to be returned, i just want the singular value from the list.  and ideally run an if statement around it to get a simple true/false

if value in column a has value 456 anywhere in column b; then true, if not false

```
ColA    ColB    ColC (desired result)
ABC     123     true
ABC     456     true
ABC     789     true
DEF     123     false
DEF     000     false
DEF     789     false
```

Comment: Have you tried using the COUNTIFS function?  This may be a good place to start, if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this will get the results I need.
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,A1,$B$1:$B$6,456)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
much simpler solution than what i was making it out to be

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it correctly, I think you want an `AND` inside of your lookup condition.  Your formula in Column C should be

`=IF(AND(A2="A*",B2=789),TRUE, FALSE)`